# Another word for "quietly confident"?

Tags: single-word-requests

A single word for "quietly confident", or "not saying much to draw attention to themselves yet having a deep sense of security"?

"Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations." Please answer with facts and citations, for example dictionary definitions.

Also how is this different from any other "single word request" which there is an official tag for

Edit, I just read this question when I came back to it and the word that came to mind was "sanguine"

Comment: See the tag for more information.

Comment: I'm not really sure how well _sanguine_ really fits, but you can add a self-answer to your question and give a definition for it if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective *secure* has the meaning of confident as well as *safe*.

**secure** (adj.)

> Confident in opinion, not entertaining or having reason to entertain doubt; certain; sure; commonly used with *of*
>
> *secure of a welcome* [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/secure)

Answer (score 1):

Words that come to mind are *poised*, *self-assured*, *self-confident*, *imperturbable*.

Of these I suggest *poised* and *imperturbable* as the best candidates. They are single (as you specify) rather than hyphenated words and both lack the overtones of *self*, reflecting how the person is seen rather than how they see themselves.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/poised?q=Poised)
>
> Poised:
>
> showing very calm and controlled behaviour

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/poised?q=Imperturbable)
>
> Imperturbable:
>
> always staying calm and controlled, even in difficult situations that would cause other people to worry

Comment: imperturbable is rare in English; common in French and Spanish, for example.

Comment: unperturbed works but poised is better

Answer (score 0):

Self-assured

confident in one's own abilities or character.
"a self-assured 16-year-old"

"The self-assured people in your life are the ones who speak up confidently, stand up for themselves, and are poised and positive. This adjective first appeared in the early 18th century, from self and assured, which shares the Latin root securus, "safe," with the word secure."

"It means you accept and trust yourself and have a sense of control in your life. You know your strengths and weakness well, and have a positive view of yourself. You set realistic expectations and goals, communicate assertively, and can handle criticism."

Comment: that has too much hustle and bustle to it, like you're puffing out your chest. your quote contradicts my specification. I was looking for something more serene, almost disquieting or eery and preemptionary (not rushing forward) if you will. sanguine works I think.